# SQL Server casting from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

In SQL Server I have a query that looks like this (part of the `WHERE` clause of a larger query)

```
SELECT 1
WHERE TPR.GRDE_PK IN
     (
          SELECT CAST(String AS INT)
          FROM dbo.Split_New(@GRADES, ',')
     )
```

`@Grades` is equal to '14,15' and `dbo.Split_New` is a function that returns a table with a single column called `String` that will contains '14' and '15'. `TPR.GRDE_PK` is of type `INT`. I get a conversion error when I try to execute this line, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Here is that the `Split_New` function looks like (Written by someone more skilled than me, so I don't understand all of it):

```
function [dbo].[Split_New] ( 
@StringToSplit nvarchar(4000),
@Separator varchar(128))
returns table as return
with indices as
( 
select 0 S, 1 E
union all
select E, charindex(@Separator, @StringToSplit, E) + len(@Separator) 
from indices
where E > S 
)
select substring(@StringToSplit,S, 
case when E > len(@Separator) then e-s-len(@Separator) else len(@StringToSplit) - s +    1 end) String
--,S StartIndex        
from indices where S >0
```

Comment: Can you post the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your TPR.GRDE_PK value is an Integer, cast it as a VARCHAR():

```
SELECT 1
WHERE CAST(TPR.GRDE_PK AS VARCHAR(25)) IN
     (
          SELECT *
          FROM dbo.Split_New(@GRADES, ',')
     )
```

The function works fine, it returns the expected table of results given your string.

Alternatively, you can avoid using the function at all with LIKE:

```
WHERE ','+CAST(TPR.GRDE_PK AS VARCHAR(25))+',' LIKE '%,'+@GRADES+',%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say exactly what it is without looking at the function.

First see if you get the correct results from the function:

```
SELECT String FROM dbo.Split_New(@GRADES, ',')
```

`String` may have leading/trailing spaces. Try to trim them before converting/casting using `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` function

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(RTRIM(String))) FROM dbo.Split_New(@GRADES, ',')
```

[ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function is not ideal to filter and convert as it returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers.

Comment: Did you try this function alone? What is your @grades string?